# Ordering by multiple columns in Sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, sunspot

### Solved

I want to have my `:price` and `:purchase_date` fields to be ordered together in my search index. So it will give the most present date and then the lowest price of the following date. How is this done?

I think there is a bug when doing:

```
order_by :purchase_date, :desc
order_by :price,:asc
```

compared to:

```
order_by(:purchase_date, :desc)
order_by(:price,:asc)
```

My finished code is like this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = UserPrice.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
      facet :business_retail_store_id, :business_online_store_id
      order_by(:purchase_date, :desc) 
      order_by(:price,:asc)
    end
    @user_prices = @search.results
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UserPrice.order(:by => [:price,:purchase_date])

UserPrice.order("price DESC, purchase_date DESC")
```

See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

---

Here's an example from the Sunspot site:

```
Post.search do
  fulltext 'best pizza'
  with :blog_id, 1
  with(:published_at).less_than Time.now
  order_by :price, :desc           # descending order , check Documentation link below
  order_by :published_at, :desc    # descending order , check Documentation link below
  paginate :page => 2, :per_page => 15
  facet :category_ids, :author_id
end
```

The Sunspot documentation says:

**order_by(field_name, direction = nil)**  Specify the order that results should be returned in. **This method can be called multiple times; precedence will be in the order given.**

See:

http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/

http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/docs/index.html

Comment: Strange, seems like a bug or something when I did `order_by :price, :asc` and `order_by :purchase_date, :desc`, it didn't do what I wanted but when I simply changed it to `order_by(:price, :asc)` and `order_by(:purchase_date, :desc)` it works. Thank you for sticking to the question and the extra code inside of the example, need to get my facets correct too.